# How to say 'before previous' in one word?

Tags: word-choice

I'm struggling to say 'before previous' in one word. 
Like "I visited my parents pre-previous month".
Is there a suitable word?

Comment: I can't think of any single word. I would say, "I visited my parents [the] month before last."

Comment: *NOUN before last* ... *I visited my parents month before last*

Comment: @StoneyB ".. **the** month before last."

Comment: @user Naw, people say that sort of thing all the time, like *I visited my folks week before last* or *I already took that test two Fridays ago*. Nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: "... two months ago."

Comment: *I visited my parents back in May.*

Comment: @tchrist unless it's a text message, or part of a conversation, my personal opinion is that leaving out **the** is a typo.

Comment: [Related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27246) on ELL with a near exhaustive list of was to refer to previous places, times, events etc.

Comment: @user It's not a typo; it's what I intended; it's how I say it; it's perfectly correct when *month* (or *week*, *year*, *century* etc) is locative rather than substantive. It's not uncommon (or incorrect) even when *month* is substantive: *Month before last was wetter than last month*.

Comment: @StoneyB I can't imagine a sentence where leaving out **the** would still sound correct *except* as a quick response, i.e. 'Q: When did you get your new glasses? A: Month before last.' I've read a lot of books, and spent 22 years in England, and *in my opinion* it just sounds wrong.

Comment: @user ***“I’ll see you Thursday.”*** Hope this helps and have a nice day.

Comment: @tchrist now you're missing an **on**! :P It's fine to say that in conversation, but I don't understand how that pertains to using **the** before *month before last*?

Comment: @user Certainly am not! It’s fine to say in conversation, fine to say in writing, fine to say in love, fine to say in the confessional. The point is that you seem to think that locatives need more window-dressing that they really do. This is merely a personal affectation unshared by millions and millions and millions and millions of native speakers.

Comment: @tchrist in anything even semi-formal, I am of the opinion that they are necessary. I don't know the rules, I only know what sounds and looks right. In a business email, I would never leave them out on purpose. I might leave them out in a verbal conversation with friends.

Comment: @user  Apparently you are unaware that this is a very well documented transatlantic flippery, and you shouldn’t think that cisatlantic use by native speakers is ipso facto wrong; to the contrary, in fact.

Comment: @tchrist I guess I won't be hiring an American copywriter anytime soon then :P (final comment, feel free to delete).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in comments, "two months ago" or "the month before last" are common ways to phrase this. As also noted on comments, some folks will drop "the" from "the month before last." That's a pretty informal mode of speech, but bear in mind that there's another "month" implied in the phrase already "the month before last [month]."

Answer (score 4):

A late answer but you can say "penultimate".

Comment: Penultimate means last but one, but that's last in the sense of the one before the _final_ one, not the one before the _previous_ one.

Comment: penultimate should work, assuming the current item is the latest item, and we are interested in the one before it.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper but in that case "penultimate" would simply be a synonym of "previous".  then you'd need "pen-pen-ultimate" and we're back at the same problem we started with

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a single word, just give the name of the month.

Comment: I'm trying to name a function in programming, it's relative to current date, takes a certain date in the month before last, can't use the specific month name because of that

Comment: Then you used a poor example, and programming terms are off topic as well.  Personally I would name it "TwoMonthsAgo()".  short, pithy names in Programming are very poor practice rather than descriptive ones.

Comment: Yeah, I know, you're right of course. But I'd like to learn this word in general, besides programming usage.

Comment: There is no such common word in English.  Someone may come up with some coined word used once in 100 years, but then nobody will know what you are saying if you used it.  As everyone is saying, the common phrase is "month before last".

Comment: If what you want is a computer code identifier, there’s no reason why you can’t use “pre_previous”.

Comment: @Oldcat Hey, isn’t `two_months_ago()` still one word? :)

Comment: it certainly is a single legal C/C++ identifier!

Comment: I've got similar problem, I need to name objects. I believe author of that question knew that he could use "TwoMonthsAgo()" or "two_months_ago()" as a function name, but he probably didn't want to use it because it's not really two months ago, it depends of current day. And it's hard to say which moment of the month was two months ago. I think "CurrentMonth()", "LastMonth()" and "MonthBeforeLast()" would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

How about “ante-previous”?  (I just made it up, but I believe that it makes sense.)

Comment: A person who hears "ante-previous" might think you said "anti-previous".

Comment: Or “Aunty Previous”. That’s a risk with any word beginning with “ante-”.

Comment: This works for me in my sentence: "As a general rule, we should never send money for a given month until the ante-previous month's accounting is complete".

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite what you're asking for, but an analogous example exists.  In British English, a reference to last Friday might be worded as "Friday week" or "Friday last".  The same idea would apply here, as, for instance, "October last".  I think it is a bit more elegant than "last October", but that might be due to the relative novelty of the phrase to American ears.