# Word to describe the one before the last one

Tags: british-english

I have a project that requires storing a latest file, previous file and 'one before the previous' file. Each will go in its own folder named: current, previous and **{one before previous}**. What do I call that third folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to say 'before previous' in one word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181869/how-to-say-before-previous-in-one-word)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this, however there isn't a name (such as September) which describes the order here.

Comment: The answers in the possible duplicates http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181869/how-to-say-before-previous-in-one-word  and  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/word-meaning-two-paragraphs-previous  aren't good for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually [antepenultimate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antepenultimate) but this word is so uncommon that most people won't know what you mean. People tend to say something like "this one, the previous one, and the one before that".

I would be delighted if more people used antepenultimate but I have been on the losing side of many linguistic battles and am not optimistic on this one.

Comment: What a great word. In conversation I would use "the one before". It seems a bit clumsy in written word though.

Comment: And, conveniently, *antepenultimate, penultimate,* and *ultimate* sort that way alphabetically - great for folks whose OCD extends to folder and directory structures!

Answer (score 1):

This is a well established procedure in computer science, and the files are called  **grandfather, father and son** files.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme

Comment: Thanks. This implys some ancestral relationship that isn't present in this application, though.

Comment: "Antepenultimate" can be used when you're referring to *versions* of files.  I don't think you'd use "father/son" terminology for versioning?